# How to use [HandleError] without Master Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages, handleerror

I am trying to use [HandleError] in MVC to redirect any un-handled exceptions to the "Error.aspx" page in the "Shared" folder. By default the Visual Studio 2010 MVC2 template creates a simple MVC application with this function. It works fine.

But the Error.aspx file created by default uses "Site.Master". But I do not want to use master page in my application. I deleted default "Error.aspx" and added my own. But it simply does not work. Anyone has any idea on how to use [HandleError] without Master page?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your custome `Error.aspx` or your custome error page in shared views

```
 [HandleError(View = "Error")] // Or your custome error page name
```